# Unicode errors when comparing two strings

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to compare two strings `last_content` and `new_content`. One string is being read from a file and the other is being passed from BeautifulSoup. When I try to compare the two, I get the following error:

`UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal`

This is how I'm populating `last_content` and `new_content`:

```
f = open('content.txt', 'r')
    last_content = str(f.read())

new_content = soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'threadtitleline'})[2]
```

And here is the conditional that is throwing the error:

```
if new_content == last_content:
        do something awesome
    else:
        do something even more awesome
```

Is there a way for me to encode these strings in order to avoid this error?

Comment: why are you calling `str()` on `f.read()`? That's changing it to type `str`, not `unicode`...

Comment: That's how the example I used explained it. I've also tried removing it and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with io.open('content.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  last_content = f.read()
```

Don't forget to do the same when writing it out.

[Unicode in Python, Completely Demystified](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this works great! The link you provided is also very helpful. Thank you again!